# how to update sql table from entity class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

i changed some of my entity classes. I added some more columns and changed some of column names. I want to learn that how can i update my sql tables according to these entities or how can i re-create these tables from my entity classes.Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a bad idea to generate Tables from Entities. So what you saying is that - every time your app starts it should create new tables. What will will happen the data already persisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in hibernate mapping:

```
<property key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

but your app would be recreate your table each time you start app.

[Also you can read this chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)